# wrong output for inf=INT_MAX

Tags: c++, bellman-ford

Below code is for Bellman Ford algorithm and it gives wrong output when I use `const int INF=INT_MAX` but correct output when I use `const int INF=1e9` in line number 3.
Any idea why?

**Code:**

```
#include"bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
const int INF=1e9;
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    vector<vector<int>> edges;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int u,v,w;
        cin>>u>>v>>w;
        edges.push_back({u,v,w});

    }
    int src;
    cin>>src;
    vector<int> dist(n,INF);
    dist[src]=0;
    for(int iter=0;iter<n-1;iter++)
    {
        for(auto e:edges)
        {
            int u=e[0];
            int v=e[1];
            int w=e[2];
            dist[v]=min(dist[v],w+dist[u]);

        }
    }
    for(auto i:dist)
    {
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }

}
```

**Sample Input:**

5 8

1 2 3

3 2 5

1 3 2

3 1 1

1 4 2

0 2 4

4 3 -3

0 1 -1

0

**Expected Output:**
0 -1 2 -2 1

Comment: See `dist[v]=min(dist[v],w+dist[u]);` - the expression `w + dist[u]` will overflow the max value of `int` if `w > 0` since all d[] are at the max for `int` already, initially. When`int` overflows, it becomes negative.

Comment: Think what happens when you add any number to INF, it will overflow and due to rounding feature of C/C++, it will become negative. Declaring INF = 1e9 works in this case because maybe the edge weights are small and after adding the edge weights, it does not overflow. But the correct way would be to check beforehand if `dist[u] == INF`

Comment: @JohnD integer overflow is UB. And even in implementations where it does wrap around, adding 2 numbers doesn't result in a negative value when overflow, because adding 2 negative numbers will result in positive result when overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signed integer overflow here `w+dist[u]`. The simple fix:

```
dist[v] = static_cast<int>(min(static_cast<long long>(dist[v]), static_cast<long long>(w) + dist[u]));
```